# Issue with UIRefresh Control

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4, uirefreshcontrol

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(ViewController.handleRefresh(_:)),
                             for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red

    return refreshControl
}()

@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    //self.expandTableView.reloadData()

    updateTimer() .  // is my function of parsing and showing json data in tableview
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

}
```

So now what happens is when I swipe and an indicator of red color comes up but fades away.
Although updateTimer() is running in the backend.
Before that only the indicator fades away.

I want the indicator to be displaying there till all the task are performed by `updateTimer()`.

Similar to the instagram pull the refresh function ( refresh icon is active till the required data is parsed).

Any way to do this ??

Comment: You should call `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` after all tasks done.

Comment: move 'refreshControl.endRefreshing()' to at the end of 'updateTimer()' function

Comment: looks like your `updateTimer` works async. So after all task done into async call this `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`